# Unable to get last window title

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, title

```
public void projectlinks() throws Exception{

        jsClick(getWebElement("project.landingPage.linkedIn"));
        String Exp_titleL = "LinkedIn: Log In or Sign Up";

        jsClick(getWebElement("project.landingPage.twitter"));
        String Exp_titleT = "project (@project_app) | Twitter";

        jsClick(getWebElement("project.landingPage.facebook"));
        String Exp_titleF = "project - Home | Facebook";

        jsClick(getWebElement("project.landingPage.googleplus"));
        String Exp_titleG = "project app - Google+";

        jsClick(getWebElement("project.landingPage.instagram"));
        String Exp_titleI = "project (@project_app) • Instagram photos and videos";

        String originalWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
        java.util.Set<java.lang.String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        for (String window: windowHandles) {
             if(!window.equals(originalWindowHandle)){
                 driver.switchTo().window(window);
                 Thread.sleep(5000);
                 String title = driver.getTitle();
                 System.out.println("current title is: " + title);   

                if(title.equals(Exp_titleT) ){
                    System.out.println("Directed to project Twitter page - success");
                }else if(title.equals(Exp_titleF)){
                    System.out.println("Directed to project Facebook page - success");
                }else if(title.equals(Exp_titleG)){
                    System.out.println("Directed to project Google+ page - success");
                }else if(title.equals(Exp_titleI)){
                    System.out.println("Directed to project Instagram page - success");
                }else if(title.equals(Exp_titleL)){
                    System.out.println("Directed to project LinkedIn page - success");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Fail - Failed to reirect");
                    }

                }
         }
```

Results:

```
Directed to project LinkedIn page - success
Directed to project Twitter page - success
Directed to project Facebook page - success
Directed to project Google+ page - success
```

Question: All links are be clicked but unable to get last window tab 'Instagram' title

Comment: Did you check if instagram opens on same page?

Comment: What is the result for the `current title is` for the Instagram page? Did it match what you have for `Exp_titleI`?

Comment: Instagram tab is opened in tab. @Tarun Lalwani

Comment: It matches with the Exp_titleI but still was not pulling the title. @HaC

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Tarun & @ HaC

All of sudden it all the titles are pulling that means the code is correct. But why it didn't run before ? Question remains in my mind..?
Any suggestions for me